# Add properties to @Cacheable annotation without using nested annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations, ehcache

So I'm using ehcache-spring-annotations 1.2.0 in a Spring Roo project and Roo has a total fit every time it runs into nested annotations that it didn't create. Is there a way to rewrite this annotation without using nested annotations?

```
@Cacheable(cacheName = "CacheName", 
           keyGenerator = @KeyGenerator (
               name = "ListCacheKeyGenerator",
               properties = {
                   @Property(name="useReflection", value="true"),
                   @Property(name="checkforCycles", value="true")}))
public void method() {
    // do something that needs cached
}
```